# Rails update code from rails 2 to rails 3 with will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm trying to update the following code on by controller:

```
@post = Post.paginate_by_user_id(@user.id, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

This was used most likely used with will_paginate plugin for rails 2

`paginate_by_user_id` or by anything else is no longer used in current will_paginate gem

Does anyone know how, I can pass the @user.id and use `Post.paginate` and keep the keep same logic as above?

I have everything else need to make this work.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => @user.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order('created_at DESC')
```

Or if your `User` model has a `has_many` relation to `posts`:

```
@posts = @user.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order('created_at DESC')
```